# creating a Table View in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode4, tableview

I'm new to Xcode 4, and having some problems with TableView.
I have a ViewController which I dragged into a TableView.
I have the source model, and created an array,
but I don't know how to get the TableView to display the values.

I don't want to use a TableViewController, because I want the table to be smaller than the IPhone screen - but without it I don't know how to connect the TableView to a controller.

can someone provide me a good step-by-step explanation of how to do it?

thanks

Comment: Amit: How about listening to the repeated advice to mark some of your past questions as accepted? At the very least, you could have modified the very similar one you just posted yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and efficient example of creating a TableView , [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Simple_iOS_5_iPhone_Table_View_Application)

Answer (score 2):

- declare your view controller as conforming to the UITableView delegate and datasource protocols
- Connect the tableview's delegate and datasource outlets to your view controller in interface builder
- implement the methods as described in the documentation.

Table view controllers give you a little extra in terms of editing mode and a few visual features on the table, but you can add a table view to a view managed by a standard view controller and be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If i understoof the question correctly to connect the smaller table to the code, you right click on the table in the interface builder and connect the delegate to the files owner it should work.

Otherwise if you check out http://www.geekylemon.com they have some really good tutorials

Cheers